# C# updating picturebox by attaching new image

Tags: c#, image

Good Day!

I was trying to make 4 images collide in one picture and while adding each picture it will update the picturebox.  [image]

However, after I tried to use the code below:

> ```
>             using (Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\emo\res1.png"))  --> this is the image that is attached to the picture box.
>             using (Image watermarkImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\emo\eyes\Eyes-01.png"))
>             using (Graphics imageGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
>             using (Brush watermarkBrush = new TextureBrush(watermarkImage))
>             {
>                 imageGraphics.FillRectangle(watermarkBrush, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), image.Size));
>                 image.Save(@"C:\emo\res1.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
>             }
>             pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"C:\emo\res1.png";
>             this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
> ```

It doesn't work because it's saying that it is being used by another process.

Comment: <sarcasm>I'm not 100% certain, but I'd say it's because it is being used by another process.</sarcasm> Seriously though, do you have either image open in photoshop?  Or have you opened either image earlier and not disposed of it?

Comment: Which line is the problematic one? Have you debugged your issue?

Comment: Nevermind my could guys, hahaha! I was trying to find a new way to combine pictures and update picturebox. Sorry for my bad post

Comment: @Luke Park, nope. I haven't opened anything. All other applications are close.

Comment: So which image does it think is open?